# The includes and where doesn't retrieve the correctly associated object

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I'm trying to implement the search feature on my project,
so I add the class method :

```
    class Donation < ActiveRecord::Base
      belongs_to :member
      def self.search_by_name name
        includes(:member).where(member:  { name: name } )
      end
    end
```

And I call it in the donatinos#index

```
    class DonationsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        search_donations
      end

      private
      def search_donations
        if !params[:name].blank?
          @donations = Donation.search_by_name params[:name]
        else
          @donations = Donation.all
        end
      end    
    end
```

Finally, I implement the index template:

```
    <%= form_tag donations_path,:method => 'get' do %>
        <%= text_field_tag :name %>
        <%= submit_tag "search", name: nil %>
    <% end %>
    <table>
        <% @donations.each do |donation| %>
        <tr>
            <td><%= donation.total %></td>
        </tr>
        <% end %>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

I got the error message after I take "Ted Wang" in the form

```
    SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: member.name: SELECT "donations"."id" AS t0_r0, "donations"."organization_id" AS t0_r1, "donations"."category" AS t0_r2, "donations"."borrow_id" AS t0_r3, "donations"."member_id" AS t0_r4, "donations"."total" AS t0_r5, "donations"."note" AS t0_r6, "donations"."created_at" AS t0_r7, "donations"."updated_at" AS t0_r8, "donations"."time" AS t0_r9, "members"."id" AS t1_r0, "members"."no" AS t1_r1, "members"."name" AS t1_r2, "members"."nick_name" AS t1_r3, "members"."introducer" AS t1_r4, "members"."role" AS t1_r5, "members"."gender" AS t1_r6, "members"."birthday" AS t1_r7, "members"."lunar_birthday" AS t1_r8, "members"."lunar_deathday" AS t1_r9, "members"."identified_number" AS t1_r10, "members"."home_phone" AS t1_r11, "members"."company_phone" AS t1_r12, "members"."bbcall" AS t1_r13, "members"."mobile" AS t1_r14, "members"."address" AS t1_r15, "members"."permanent_address" AS t1_r16, "members"."education" AS t1_r17, "members"."job" AS t1_r18, "members"."created_at" AS t1_r19, "members"."updated_at" AS t1_r20, "members"."organization_type" AS t1_r21, "members"."organization_id" AS t1_r22, "members"."involved" AS t1_r23 FROM "donations" LEFT OUTER JOIN "members" ON "members"."id" = "donations"."member_id" WHERE "member"."name" = 'Ted Wang'
```

Did I use `includes` wrong?
and member has the attribute name, I also ran the db:migrate.

Comment: Save yourself the pain of reinventing the wheel then seeing there's something better premade, like Ransack => https://www.ruby-toolbox.com/categories/Active_Record_Named_Scopes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As per Rails convention, table names are lower cased and pluralized model names so in the where clause you should specify `members` (in *plural*) and NOT `member` (in *singular*).

You can easily debug this looking at the error message: `SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: member.name`. With the error message, one can diagnose that the table name is `members` so something in the query is definitely wrong as its referring to `member.name` instead of `members.name`.

```
def self.search_by_name name
  includes(:member).where(members: { name: name } )
  ##                       ^
  ##                       plural
end
```

Comment: It works! Thanks a lot!
I forgot the where() is specify on table not like `donation.member.where(name: name).

Answer (score 1):

```
 def self.search_by_name name
    includes(:member).where("members.name = ?", name)
 end
```

Everything else stays the same .

Answer (score 0):

You could use a scope (this is generally the standard way of specifying queries via methods in rails)

```
scope :filter_by_member_name, lambda { |name| select("*").where("donations d, members m").where("d.member_id= m.id").where("m.name LIKE ?",  "%#{value}%") if name }
```

then inside your controller

```
@donations = Donation.filter_by_member_name(params[:name])
```

by joining members and donations manually, you don't need active record to fire up two queries and piece together everything.

Just replace the arguments inside the select().